# How can I get an <iframe> container to enclose my <svg> element without scroll bars or padding around the <svg> element?

Tags: javascript, html, svg, iframe

I am trying to dynamically create an SVG image within JS in a static HTML document. I created an empty  iframe element on my page. Please note that I am using this as a learning exercise so it's built with static elements. I am not referencing any external sites (thus no bootstrap or other packages).

The iframe code I am currently using (on the .html page) is below.

In my JS code I want to adjust the height and width to create a box surrounding my SVG image. The SVG header I generated is:
The challenge I can't overcome is that when the width and height dimensions from the svg header are assigned to the iframe height and width, I get a vertical scroll bar on the right side. If I add 16 units to the iframe height the scroll bar goes away but now there's a blank area at the bottom of the image. When I examine it in the browser (Chrome) developer tools I can't get a fix on what that area is a part of. I've played with padding, margins, and anything else I can find that makes sense. I may resort to having no border around my iframe (which is ok) but I'd like to learn from this what can be done.

As a side note, I have seen advice on the web about using a div element inside my iframe and that's ok too. I'm not sure it's significant but the svg image I am generating will be downloaded and used as a standalone image, hence my use of an iframe in the first place.

Thank you for your patience in this long winded question.

On my html page:

```
    <iframe
      id="ifBarcodeImage"
      name="ifBarcodeImage"
      style="border:1px solid red; padding:0px; margin:0px; display:auto"
      height="200px"
      width="200px"
      srcdoc=""
    />
```

And generated in my js code:

```
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
viewBox="0 0 324 120" enable-background="new 0 0 324 120" xml:space="preserve">
.
.
.
</svg>
```

Finally, this is a screen clipping of the resulting image. Ideally I would like the blue rectangle to display inside the red rectangle with no border/padding around it. Alternately, I would be alright with the whole svg image centered in the iframe. The blue rectangle is my attempt to see the outer limits of the view box and will not be part of my finished project.

[image]

Comment: Why the ``<iframe>``?

Comment: Perhaps the aspect ratio of the svg does not match the iframe aspect ratio. Do you want it to deform, Overflow or be cut off in that case?

Comment: In order to preserve the aspect ratio (width / height) and if you need to have width:200px for the iframe try using height:height:74px;

Comment: I am enclosing the svg within an iframe because I want to download the svg into a file using a download process. Thus I need the file headers to use the svg as an image file in Word, Excel, etc. I found if I built my svg elements without the  <?xml . . . > and <!DOCTYPE svg . . . > headers I could not get it to load elsewhere. My understanding is that I must use the iframe to "host" this type of page. I change the initial sizes to match the svg size in js. Ultimately I would probably hide the iframe until I populated it, then I would show it. I have no preconceived ideas about the iframe size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For an SVG to **fit in its container** you need to set `preserveAspactRatio="none"` on the SVG

No need for an IFRAME when you

- create a native Web Component `<fit-svg src="your.svg">`,
  with shadowDOM so you don't have to worry about CSS or duplicate IDs in your SVG
- that *fetches* the external SVG defined in the `src` attribute
- sets all required `<style>`
- injects the *fetched* SVG
- sets `preserveAspactRatio="none"` on the SVG
- since everyone complains about shadowDOM being difficult to style,
  I wacked in an extra `...this.children` to *move* all lightDOM to shadowDOM

```html
<script>
  // define <fit-svg> anytime you like. There is no ONLOAD/PARSED dependency
  customElements.define("fit-svg", class extends HTMLElement {
    async connectedCallback() {
      this.attachShadow({mode:"open"}).innerHTML = "";
      this.shadowRoot.append(
          Object.assign(document.createElement("style"), {
              innerHTML: ":host{ display:inline-block   }" +
                         "div  { width:100%;height:100% }" +
                         "svg  { height:100%;width:100% }"
          }),
          Object.assign(document.createElement("div"), {
              innerHTML: await (await fetch(this.getAttribute("src"))).text()
          }),
          ...this.children
      )
      this.shadowRoot.querySelector("svg")
                     .setAttribute('preserveAspectRatio', 'none');
    }
  })
</script>
<style>
  #SVG1 { width:100px;height:150px;background:pink }
  #SVG2 { width:300px;height:180px;background:pink }
</style>
<!-- NOW ALL HTML REQUIRED IS: -->
<fit-svg id=SVG1 src="//svg-cdn.github.io/heart.svg">
     <style> path:nth-child(2n+2) { fill: GREEN } </style>
</fit-svg>
<fit-svg id=SVG2 src="//svg-cdn.github.io/heart.svg">
     <style> path:nth-child(2n+2) { fill: RED } </style>
</fit-svg>
```

[image]

Comment: That's great information, BUT, I want the iframe to enclose the generated svg with the svg dimensions. I am only generating a small graphic, not something like a map of the universe. Thus my graphic will be printable at full scale on a letter sized paper. I want the aspect ratio preserved and I want the boundary of the iframe to fit the size of the svg. Perhaps I don't need an iframe, but I want to download this generated image onto my local hard disk and I thought I understood that an iframe was AN approach to that. Perhaps I'm overthinking this.

Comment: Maybe rephrase your question, You want output to paper. And your SVG does not have the correct aspect-ratio??

Comment: Truly, your information gave me the guidance I needed to get this done right. I learned a lot. What I failed to consider was that the body of the iframe document has styles and attributes too (duh). So once I traced through that part of the hierarchy (and more searching that yielded things that finally made sense because of your help) I found what I wanted. Instead of the svg fitting the container, I wanted the container to enclose the boundaries of the drawn svg. Plus I learned about creating elements & not creating hardcoded html "strings". Much cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add the attribute `scrolling=“no”` to your iframe. Technically it was deprecated years ago when HTML5 was first released, however, every browser fully supports this and that is unlikely to ever change, as it would break too many existing websites. Currently this still cannot be achieved with CSS.

Comment: This should solve the scroll bar issue. But I am still left with my svg image in the top 2/3 of the iframe. When I examine the elements in Chrome, there is an area I cannot point to and have it highlight. Plus the units for x and y do not correspond to the px units I assign to the height/width. The assigned values are the height/width of the svg (which are in px [pixels]).

Comment: Perhaps the iframe-resizer library can help with this.